# How can I set up integers in phpMyAdmin to be unsigned by default?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I set up integers in phpMyAdmin to be unsigned by default? Most times I am setting them to be auto-incremented, and I don't need the negative values. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `common.inc.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['js_include'][] = 'extension.js';
```

Create a file called `extension.js` in the `js` folder:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#create_table_form select[name=tbl_collation]').val('utf8_general_ci');
    $('#append_fields_form select.column_type, #create_table_form select.column_type').live('change keyup',function(k,v){
        var field = $(this).attr('name').replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('[name="field_attribute['+field+']"] option').attr('selected',false);
        $('[name="field_collation['+field+']"] option').attr('selected',false);
        $('[name="field_length['+field+']"]').val('');
        if(val == 'VARCHAR'){
            $('[name="field_length['+field+']"]').val('255');
            $('[name="field_collation['+field+']"]').val('utf8_general_ci');
        }
        if(val == 'INT'){
            $('[name="field_attribute['+field+']"]').val('UNSIGNED');
            $('[name="field_length['+field+']"]').val('11');
        }   
    });
});
```

Tested with phpMyAdmin 3.4.2. Also sets a few other nice defaults.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible in the later version of phpMyAdmin using the Attributes option.

Comment: When adding a new column, sixth option across is "Attributes". Binary, Unsigned, Unsigned zerofill, and on update current timestamp. Setting Unsigned here will give you an unsigned int column.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question - the behavior I want to see is that when I select the type as "Int" I want it to be "Unsigned" by default...

Answer (score 4):

1. Setting integers unsigned via UI.

   - Open the dropdown menu against the Attributes column in the table structure.
   - Select "unsigned" and click save.

[image: unsigned screenshot phpmyadmin]

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this by default. However you can check multiple columns and click edit to change those at once via the phpmyadmin UI as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible via UI ...
You should edit/implement it in the phpMyAdmin source code ...

A link with additional info about phpMyAdmin development: [link](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/improve.php)
A link to developer wiki: [link](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Development)
You should use [GIT](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGit_%28software%29&rct=j&q=git&ei=C1IkTtPGHMOCtgfhvMCiAw&usg=AFQjCNF-3SEMy2Sve5Ptar_OR-42U87AdA&sig2=Jq7pP8SmOTFlKJ-B_OVlZQ&cad=rja) to get working with the source code.

There you can get the source code and implement that feature.

Good luck!

Comment: how about a link to writing a plugin or extension for phpMyAdmin?